# java closest combination algorithm

Tags: java

I have a quick question about an algorithm in java.
Im sure it's been done somewhere but i just cant think of it.

Say i have a group of numbers e.g. an example to explain is football players

```
Player 1: Speed 120 / Skill 12 / footwork 9
Player 2: Speed 160 / Skill 16 / footwork 16
Player 3: ...
Player 4: ...
and so on.
```

I will have an end number like "I want the skill = 1320, speed = 60, footwork = 80
And the output of the algorithm to tell me 
"Player 1, player 4, player 6 and player 12 will = skill, 1320 (closest it can make) speed 61, footwork 80.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction of this algorithm , or a similar one that has a name i can research.

Thank you

Comment: You have to deifine a metric, i.e. "difference in 1 of skill is equal to difference in 15 of footwork"

Comment: This sounds like the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: It's a classical [linear optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem, you should take a look to the [Simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the Coin change algorithm to replace all possible coin denominations with the available values in each attribute could work.

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

You will have to add a little wiggle room for "close enough" but this should get you the basic algorithm needed.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple way is to check players skill/footwork/etc.. in a range.

For example you search a player with ( speed = 110, skill =15, footwork = 12).

So your program will search a player with  speed = 110(+/-10%) skill =15(+/-10%), footwork = 12(+/-10%).

Maybe not the best solution, but quite easy to realize ^^

Answer (score 0):

also see here: http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy562/lectures14/week2a_ranking.pdf
skyline...and generaly Ranking in Databases.